# Figure out at what time the machine was suspended

Tags: arch-linux, logs, systemd, suspend

I suspended my machine and now got back to work. I want to figure out at what time I suspended the machine. Is there any way to somehow look up the time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is printed to the journal. You can read it with `journalctl | grep Suspend`:

```
Mar 31 15:28:29 Shiv systemd[1]: Started Suspend.
```

Comment: What about systems without `systemd`?

Comment: @petry No idea: the question is an [tag:arch-linux] one, so I answered with respect to that init system.